# installing Aquila dsp lib

Tags: visual-studio, signals

I am trying to instal aquila lib using link [this](http://nip-saga.blogspot.com.tr/2015/06/configure-aquila-digital-signal-processing-libraray-visual-studio.html). But when i write "mingw32-make", it gives the following error.

Mingw32-make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The way I installed this library was by using CMake (https://cmake.org/download/) as it specifies it as a requisite on the Aquila Website (http://aquila-dsp.org/download/).

The default CXX and C compiler on the CMakeLists.txt are not MinGW32. So, in order to change this just open up the CMake GUI which will be in the bin folder of wherever you installed it.

Then click "Browse Source" and choose the directory where the CMakeLists.txt file is. Last thing is to create a new folder in that same directory because that will force CMake to let you specify the type of Makefile it will generate. Then, of course, you choose to build the Makefile in the new folder you just made, and when you hit configure you will choose MinGW Makefile in the dropdown list...configure...generate...mingw32-make the Makefile in the build folder.